# Using ColdFusion to output thumbnails on the fly to jCarousel unordered list

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm using jCarouselLite to show thumbnails of pages of an advertisement. When you click on the thumbnail the my code populates a div below the carousel with the larger image. All of that works great with hard coded thumbnails in the list.

What I need to know is, what is the best way to create the thumbnails from the larger images so my client only has to upload the larger images and I can control the thumbnail image size?

Is it more efficient to create the thumbnails on upload and store them in a thumbnails directory or, is there a way I can have ColdFusion create a thumbnail on the fly from the larger image and populate my list of thumbnails without having to store a thumbnail on the server?

I'm using CF8. Right now everything is hard coded but in the future the page will make a call to a CFC that will return the `href` info.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Capture the click from the thumbnail to set the large image //
$('.image_thumb ul li').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var imgSource = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var imgNow = $('.main_image img').attr('src');
    $('.main_image img').attr('src', imgSource);
    //alert(imgSource + " And the main image Now is " + imgNow);

});

//Initiate jCarouselLite //
$(function() {
    $(".image_thumb").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        circular: false,
        easing: "bounceout",
        speed: 1000
    });
});

//End Doc Function
});
```

My page:

```
<div id="thumbs">                   
<div class="image_thumb">
<button class="prev">&lt;</button>
<button class="next">&gt;</button>
<ul>

<!-- add images to each ot the list items -->
    <li>
        <a href="pg1.jpg"><img src="pg1_t.jpg" alt="The Biggest Sale" title="The BIGGEST Sale" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="pg2.jpg"><img src="pg2_t.jpg" alt="The Biggest Sale" title="The BIGGEST Sale" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="pg3.jpg"><img src="pg3_t.jpg" alt="The Biggest Sale" title="The BIGGEST Sale" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="pg4.jpg"><img src="pg4_t.jpg" alt="The Biggest Sale" title="The BIGGEST Sale" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <<a href="pg5.jpg"><img src="pg5_t.jpg" alt="The Biggest Sale" title="The BIGGEST Sale" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="pg6.jpg"><img src="pg6_t.jpg" alt="The Biggest Sale" title="The BIGGEST Sale" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


<ul id="list1">
<div class="main_image">
<!-- Don't forget to add the first image here! -->
<img  src="pg1.jpg" alt="The BIGGEST Sale" />
</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best approach is create a resized the thumbnail on upload, because resizing is resource intensive.

You can use  to accomplish this:

```
<cfimage action=resize" source="/path/to/file.ext" 
  destination="/path/to/thumbnail-file.ext" height="25%" width="25%"/>
```

If you don't want to write the thumbnail to do the resize and then:

```
<cfimage action=resize" source="/path/to/file.ext" 
  height="25%" 
  width="25%" 
  name="oResizedImage"/>    
<cfimage action="writetobrowser" source="#oResizedImage#"/>
```

If you use this latter approach you actually get back the image data as response instead of an href.

Comment: I was thinking that would be better but wasn't 100% certain. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the route I ended up taking `<cfset local.uploadedImage = ImageNew(#destdir# & #arguments.qqfile#)>` Then... create a thumbnail: `<cfset ImageScaleToFit(#local.uploadedImage#, 72, "", "highPerformance")> <cfimage action="write" source="#local.uploadedImage#" destination="#local.newThumbName#" overwrite="yes" >`

Comment: @Ofeargall: CF functions work just as well. Shame that they're such a pollution of the namespace, instead of `image.resize()` for instance.

Comment: I used the `ImageScaleToFit()` route because I could have better control over the image compression algorithm on the larger images (not so much on the thumbnails). I'm actually a commercial photographer by trade so I'm kind of snobbish about that...